# How to apply drop_duplicates to grouped dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

I'm trying  to drop the duplicate rows in each chunk of a grouped dataframe. A toy example is

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'], \
            ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones([8,2]), index=index)
print(df)
```

The output is:

```
              0  1
first second      
bar   one     1  1
      two     1  1
baz   one     1  1
      two     1  1
foo   one     1  1
      two     1  1
qux   one     1  1
      two     1  1
```

However, if I try

```
print(df.groupby(level='first').apply(lambda d: d.drop_duplicates()))
```

then I get

```
                    0  1
first first second      
bar   bar   one     1  1
baz   baz   one     1  1
foo   foo   one     1  1
qux   qux   one     1  1
```

Is there any way to do what I need without having the extra 'first' index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `group_keys=False` to the [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby):

```
In [273]:
df.groupby(level='first', group_keys=False).apply(lambda d: d.drop_duplicates())

Out[273]:
              0  1
first second      
bar   one     1  1
baz   one     1  1
foo   one     1  1
qux   one     1  1
```

Comment: So simple! Thanks a million!